# How to see Appointment Info in E-Mail Calendar App

Tags: email, calendar, stock-email-app

I have a Motorola Android Phone with KitKat (however I think this issue applies to Android in general).

When I receive some appointment on my Exchange Account, it appears on the inbox, however the main view does not show any details about the appointment. So I have to open the "Appointment" tab and show the item in the Calendar, I have no other way to see the details of the appointment.

This is OK for new appointments, as looking into the calendar makes sense. However, it is common that appointments are changed, and this pattern does not help me to quickly recognize what was changed (location, description, timestamp). Worst thing is that opening the "changed" appointment in Calendar often does not even show the correct time (it just insists on the original time from the appointment).

I would like to see a view that shows exactly what changed on the appointment. Is there any way to get such a feature? I would even be willing to buy an app if it is necessary... :)